# How to know the end of an ANSI control code?

Tags: serial-port, escape-characters, serial-console, cursor, ansi

I'm working on code for a serial terminal and I'm implementing the ANSI escape codes for moving around the cursor, clearing the screen, etc, and I am curious how to know which to use since there doesn't seem to be a clear stopping point for the codes.

I'm using https://www2.ccs.neu.edu/research/gpc/VonaUtils/vona/terminal/vtansi.htm as a reference

For example, if I receive the  code,
I start reading characters, but if I get the value 75='K', that could be `ESC[K` = Erase End of Line, or a 75 as a count for a code like `ESC[{COUNT=75}C` for move cursor 75 columns right.
What if I was receiving the code to erase the line followed by a printed A? As far as I know the code for that and the cursor 75 cols right would receive the exact same sequence.

I'm probably missing something obvious but could someone please give me a hint? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For "ANSI" (actually [**`ECMA-48`**](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-48/)), the characters which begin the control sequence, determine the set of *final* characters.  It's documented near the beginning of **`ECMA-48`** ([section 5.4](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ecma-48-parameter-format.html) is particularly pertinent, though you may need an ASCII chart to understand its terminology).

The *parameter* **75** in a control sequence would be the characters <kbd>`7`</kbd><kbd>`5`</kbd>, rather than a character whose value happened to be *75*.  There's no confusion between the two.

The link you cited was for a document written by someone who was unfamiliar with the standard.  It's mentioned in the ncurses FAQ [*How do I get color with VT100?*](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#vt100_color).